# deploy laravel application to azure kubernetes using azure devops

Tags: laravel, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-aks

i'm struggling a lot with a Laravel application that i want to deploy to azure AKS using azure DevOps

the thing is i'm reading a lots of non-accurate tutorials and docs, i didnt found anything related on how to push or deploy a Laravel docker image to azure aks using azure DevOps and it's frustrating,

can someone help me with that by giving me some hints or tutorials ?

thank you !

Comment: Instead of following tutorials to the letter with no deeper understanding of what you're doing or why you're doing it, try to actually understand the tools involved and each step in the process, then ask a specific question if you have trouble implementing one of those steps. You need to build the container, push it to a container registry, and then either run a series of `kubectl` commands or create Kubernetes manifests that tell Kubernetes how to run the containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > how to push or deploy a Laravel docker image to azure aks using azure DevOps

Agree with Daniel, you need to [build the container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/build-image?view=azure-devops), [push it to a container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/push-image?view=azure-devops), [here](http://Build%20and%20publishing%20Docker%20images) is the detailed official tutorial. And then either run a series of kubectl commands or create Kubernetes manifests that tell Kubernetes how to run the containers.

In addition, this doc: [Deploy a Docker container app to Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-aks?view=azure-devops&tabs=java) will show you how to set up continuous deployment of your containerized application to an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) using Azure Pipelines.

BTW, videos: [Getting started with CI/CD & Azure Container Service (AKS) powered by VSTS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMIxLaisKiI) and [CI-CD for Azure Kubernetes Service AKS using Azure DevOps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4uNl6JA7g8) are also helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your help !